# Python function not running from cmd, path variables are defined and python console is functional

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

1. I am using python 3.6.8 on my Windows 10 machine. I have added python to the PATH environment variable and the python console is functional via the command prompt.
2. I have written a simple hello world script to convert into an exe using pyinstaller. This works well.
3. The issue is when I wrap the same code in a `main()` method (code below), and subsequently create the exe file, cmd just opens and closes very fast.

I have tried this first using python 3.7.1 and (2) - (3) as described above did not work at all. I then downgraded my python version to python 3.6.8 and (2) was resolved, however (3) is still an issue. The code (3) can be executed via the Windows command prompt using `python -c "import main; print(main.main())"`, so there are no issues with the code itself.

### Source Code for **(2)** as defined above (`hello.py`)

```
print("Hello World")
input("Press any key to exit")
```

### Source Code for **(3)** (`main.py`):

```
def main():
  print("Hello World")
  input("Press any key to exit")
```

### Using PyInstaller to create **(2)**:

- Navigate to source directory.
- `Shift + Right Click` and select command window here.
- `pyinstaller --onefile hello.py`

### Using PyInstaller to create **(3)** (`main.py`):

- Navigate to source directory.
- `Shift + Right Click` and select command window here.
- `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

Is there a solution to my problem? I have written a small game as a project and I want to make that game executable (release 1.0.0) for Windows with the user not required to have python installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven’t actually called main() in your code. 
Add this to the bottom.

```
def main():
  print("Hello World")
  input("Press any key to exit")

if __name__== "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Why do you imply `if __name__ == "__main__":` should not be used with Python 3? It's still the standard recommended practice.

Comment: I haven't used this much with Python 3, only with python 2.7. Based on [this site](https://www.guru99.com/learn-python-main-function-with-examples-understand-main.html) I understood that `if __name__ == "__main__":` wasn't necessary for python 3. But I guess that even if this is the case, the if-statement would still be clearer.

Comment: The site you link to doesn't seem to be saying it's not necessary or useful; it simply explains what it does and why it's common practice. The last paragraph is simply false, as you can easily demonstrate for yourself.

Comment: @tripleee I was going by the last paragraph. I hadn’t checked it, since I’m not running Python 3 on my home computer. Thanks for correcting me then.